# Single-Sign-On from Windows Workstation to PHP script running on Linux server that is not part of the same domain

Tags: php, ldap, single-sign-on

Edit: After researching further this morning I have tried to make my post more specific:

I have a php script running on a web server in my company's data centre. A client of ours needs to access that script from their user's windows workstations using single-sign-on. The php server does not have access to the domain that the windows users are logged on to.

Is there a way for the users to open Internet Explorer (or similar), go to the website I am developing and the website 'know' their username? The site will also need to deny access to anyone that is not part of the client's domain.

So to be clear, the main issue I am experiencing is that the server the php script runs on IS NOT part of the domain that the users accessing it are on.

Side note: if true SSO is not possible and the user has to retype their username and password again, that is ok, but I guess this would mean the authentication is done by the php script, which would be impossible because it cannot access the clients AD server.

Thanks :)

Original post:

Just after some links or general information to begin with. I am building a php based website on example1.com but to access it, users need to authenticate against active directory on example2.local. The domain controller for example2.local is not accessible on the internet. Users will be logged on to Windows workstations in example2.local domain and have internet accessibility though.

Is there any way this can work? I have been told to look into 'single sign on', but everything I've found so far suggests the ad domain should be example2.com (not .local). A colleague here assures me that domain controllers are not normally accessible to the wider internet.. so how is this normally done?

Also the client this is for has emphasized the need for security.

Thanks

Edit: After reading some more about SSO I'm possibly more confused, but I would like to add that all my php application needs to know is that 1) the user is authenticated in their domain and 2) their username. What is the simplest way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php

I actually just implemented a basic LDAP authentication script. This was my first draft of the script before I changed and messed with it to fit with my setup. This basically connects to the server, if not the scrpt is killed. Then tries to authenticate the given username and password, if not, it fails. Quick and simple.

```
$ldapHost = "example2.com";
$ldapPort = 666;
$ldapBaseDn = "ldap base dn here";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$ldapUserDn = "uid=$username,".$ldapBaseDn;

echo "LDAP query test\n";
echo "Connecting ...\n";
$ldapConn = ldap_connect($ldapHost, $ldapPort)
    or die("Unable to connect to LDAP server: $ldapHost\n");

echo "Authenticating user ...\n";
$isValid = ldap_bind($ldapConn, $ldapUserDn, $password)
    or die("Unable to authenticate user: $username\n");

echo "User $username is successfully authenticated!\n";

echo "Closing connection ...\n";
ldap_close($ldapConn);

exit();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks yes I have done LDAP auth this way for a host that can be accessed across the internet. The problem I have here though is that the domain controller cannot be accessed via the internet. I've updated my original question to make this clearer.